# Remove author id from query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have posts where the author is assigned as Co-Author. If i want to show them on my author page, they are not listed. Because of this condition in the query:

```
AND (wp_posts.post_author = 53)
```

How can i remove it? Or is there any better solution?

```
public static function pre_get_posts($query)
{
  if ($query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()):
    $author = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
    $authorPostIDs = self::getAuthorsPostIDs($author->ID);
    $coAuthorPostIDs = self::getCoAuthorsPostsIDs($author->ID);
    $postIDs = array_unique(
      array_merge($coAuthorPostIDs, $authorPostIDs), SORT_REGULAR
    );

    $query->set('post__in', $postIDs);
    $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
  endif;
}
```

My full query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.ID IN (349956,327745)
AND (wp_posts.post_author = 53)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Point out how the  Co-Author information stored? Because default wp_posts table doen't have this field.

Comment: I store the Co-Author id with ACF-Plugin as meta_key "acf_additional_author_1".

Comment: Use the `get_posts` function. You can pass co-author meta as a criteria there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I know that already, but i have to use pre_get_posts and manipulate the main query....

Comment: IMO it will be more easy compared to SQL

Comment: You're absolutely right. But i can't make a new query request because there are too many things related to each other...